# media query for iPad and other tablet devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad, media-queries

I am trying to write a media query to make the site look proper in the iPad.

I've got all device css files as mobile.css. And under mobile.css here's how I am making some changes.

Below is the CSS code snippet.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {


 .tobeaddedtobutton {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-image: url("../assets/tablet/btn-border-yellow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Signika;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    font-size: 13px;
     }

     .tobeaddedtobutton-1 {
     background-color: transparent;
     width: 100%;
     height: 35px;
     border-radius: 0px;
     background-image: url("../assets/tablet/btn-border-orange.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     text-align: left;
     font-family: Signika;
     color: white;
     border: none;
     font-size: 13px;
     }
    }
```

Simply I am trying to add a different border image to the buttons when the device is iPad. But when I am changing the path under this media query, broweser is reading this code for all the devices, which is not correct.

Am I doing it right?

Please suggest.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What do you mean by "But when I am changing the path under this media query, broweser is reading this code for all the devices, which is not correct." ?

Comment: Your media query will set any device that has a viewport less than 1024 pixels to use those styles. You shouldn't target just iPad anyway, you should change styles as and when the site layout becomes messy

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes (which is not much), you cannot detect the user-agent or user-platform using css only! Is there any reason, you wan't to avoid using JS? You may also store UA info in a html attribute using js  and then use css to apply styling based on those attributes!

Comment: Your missing the closing bracket off the media query

Comment: I have to apply `background-image` to couple of buttons only for iPad. For all the other devices, the images will be different and few other small arrangements and hence using this way

Comment: @jsg that was just a miss by mistake

Answer (score 2):

These are my media queries I use. I use Google Chrome Tools to switch between mobile device screen sizes.

I have noticed that even though things may look right in Google Chrome's tools that a lot of times I have to hack a media query to make things work properly on the actual device. Unfortunately you never know till you can test on an actual device.

In order to give you a lot of different examples of working media queries I left my styles in them from a site I previously worked on.

Let me know if you need me to clarify anything!

```
/* Iphone 4 */
@media screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px) 
{ 
    .newsletterDownload a  { 
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
}

/* Iphone 5 */
@media screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 568px) 
{ 
    .newsletterDownload a  { 
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
}

/* Iphone 6 */
@media screen 
and (min-device-width: 375px) 
and (max-device-width: 667px) { 
    .newsletterDownload a  { 
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
}

/* Iphone 6 plus */
@media screen 
and (min-device-width: 414px) 
and (max-device-width: 736px) 
{ 
    .newsletterDownload a  { 
        padding-left: 80px;
    }
}

/* I Pad Portrait */
@media screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
{  
.newsletterDownload a  { 
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.hours  { 
    padding-left: 0px;
}
}

/* I Pad Landscape */
@media screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) 
{ 
.newsletterDownload a  { 
    padding-left: 80px;
}
}

/* Blackberry Play Book*/
@media screen 
and (min-device-width : 600px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) 
{ 
.newsletterDownload a  { 
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.hours {
    padding-left: 16px;
}
}

/* Blackberry Z30 */
@media screen 
and (min-device-width: 360px) 
and (max-device-width: 640px) 
{ 
    .newsletterDownload a  { 
        padding-left: 47px;
    }
}

/* Nexus 6 */
@media screen 
and (min-device-width: 412px) 
and (max-device-width: 732px) 
{ 
    .newsletterDownload a  { 
        padding-left: 78px;
    }
}

/* Nexus 7 */
@media screen 
and (min-device-width: 600px) 
and (max-device-width: 960px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
{ 
    .newsletterDownload a  { 
        padding-left: 37px;
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}

/* Nexus 7 */
@media screen 
and (min-device-width: 600px) 
and (max-device-width: 960px) 
and (orientation : landscape) 
{ 
    .newsletterDownload a  { 
        padding-left:85px;
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
```

And here is iphone with a background image. Remember you will have to make sure to get all Iphone queries for each size screen and landscape vs portrait views.

```
   /* Iphone 6 plus */
    @media screen 
    and (min-device-width: 414px) 
    and (max-device-width: 736px) 
    { 
        .MyClass  { 
            background-image: url('filePathTo/image.png') repeat-x;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i think there was a specific media query for screen pixel-ratio (dpi) so you could detect retina devices (e.g. iPhones/Tablets) where you could add a simple min-width and there you go... Tablet-Query.

Example:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {

      /* Small screen, non-retina */

    }

    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
    only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
    only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 320px),
    only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 320px),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 320px) { 

      /* Small screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */

    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {

      /* Medium screen, non-retina */

    }

    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
    only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
    only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 700px),
    only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 700px),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 700px) { 

      /* Medium screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */

    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {

      /* Large screen, non-retina */

    }

    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
    only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
    only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 1300px),
    only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 1300px),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 1300px) { 

      /* Large screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */

    }
```